# In Rails 6: Parallax works in development but not in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parallax, ruby-on-rails-6

The following code works in development but not in production and I'm at a loss. I'm currently deploying production to AWS with capistrano:

```
.container_parallax {
    text-align: center;
    background-image:url(background1.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    font-family:helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    line-height:20px;
    min-height: 90vh;
}
```

The image `background1.jpg` is in the proper directory `app/assets/images/`.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by making the following change `background-image: asset-url('background1.jpg');`.